# When an index is created from a function on a column, we get the function name instead of the column name in pg_attribute in Postgres. How to fix it?

Tags: postgresql, index, pg-catalog, postgresql-16

I have come up with the following query to get the table name, index_type, operator_classes, and uniqueness of indexes based on the answers mostly from @Erwin Brandstetter:

```sql
SELECT i.indrelid::regclass::text AS table
     , c.relname AS index_name
     , a.amname AS index_type
     , opc.operator_classes
     , i.indisunique AS is_unique
     , array_agg(att.attname) as column_names
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute att ON att.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_index     i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_am        a ON a.oid = c.relam
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (SELECT opc.opcname
                 FROM   unnest(i.indclass::oid[]) WITH ORDINALITY o(oid, ord)
                 JOIN   pg_opclass opc ON opc.oid = o.oid
                 ORDER  BY o.ord)
   ) opc(operator_classes)
WHERE  n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
AND    c.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r', 't', 'i'])
group by
   i.indrelid, c.relname, a.amname, opc.operator_classes, i.indisunique
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

This works great, except it returns the wrong column names when the index is created by transforming data from another column. For example, with the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX _ixtr_luxury_inventory_images ON public.luxury_inventory
 USING gin (f_textarr2text(images) gin_trgm_ops)
```

returns:

```
table            | luxury_inventory
index_name       | _ixtr_luxury_inventory_images
index_type       | gin
operator_classes | ['gin_trgm_ops']
is_unique        | False
column_names     | ['f_textarr2text']
```

We get `f_textarr2text` as the column name instead of `images`.

How can we get the correct column_names?
I'm on Postgres 16.2 if that matters.

Update:
Here is the table creation SQL:

```sql
create table "luxury_inventory" (
id bigserial primary key,
images text[])

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public".f_textarr2text(text[]) 
RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS $$SELECT array_to_string($1, ',')$$;
```

Comment: can you please post the create table of luxury_inventory

Comment: @nbk Sure. Added the details!

Comment: You could look at `pg_depend` to see on which columns the index depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking on this for a moment, perhaps better than `pg_get_indexdef` is pulling column ordinals out of the `indexprs` column noted in the first answer, and specifically the `varattno` field.

`regexp_matches` over the 'indexprs' (converting `pg_tree_node` to `text`) for `varattno`)

I threw together the following, going back to the definition in the `columns` table of `information_schema`:

```
SELECT (SELECT JSON_AGG(columns.column_name)
          FROM information_schema.columns
         WHERE table_schema = 'public'
           AND table_name   = i.indrelid::regclass::text
           AND ordinal_position IN (SELECT matches[1]::INTEGER 
                                    FROM regexp_matches(i.indexprs::TEXT,
                                                        'varattno (\d)',
                                                        'g') as matches)) AS argument_columns
     , pg_get_indexdef(att.attrelid, att.attnum, true) 
     , i.indrelid::regclass::text AS table
     , c.relname AS index_nameq
     , att.attname as column_names
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute att ON att.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_index     i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid
WHERE  n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
AND    c.relkind IN ('r', 't', 'i')
```

and that produces:

| argument_columns | pg_get_indexdef | table | index_nameq | column_names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *NULL* | content_tsv | file_lookup_16k | fl_16k_tsv_idx | content_tsv |
| *NULL* | content_tsv | file_lookup_4k | fl_4k_tsv_idx | content_tsv |
| *NULL* | file_id | file_lookup_4k | date_index | file_id |
| ["file_id"] | abs(file_id) | file_lookup_4k | date2_index | abs |
| ["sequence_no"] | round(sequence_no::double precision) | file_lookup_4k | date3_index | round |
| ["sequence_no"] | round(sequence_no::double precision) | file_lookup_4k | date4_index | round |
| ["content"] | "substring"(content, 1, 5) | file_lookup_4k | date5_index | substring |
| ["file_id", "sequence_no"] | abs(file_id - sequence_no) | file_lookup_4k | date6_index | abs |
| *NULL* | content_tsv | file_lookup_8k | fl_8k_tsv_idx | content_tsv |

I feel that this is far more in line with what we would both want.

Note that:

- I joined only to the `attname` table, because that is really all I need
- `JSON_AGG(columns.column_name)` can be replaced with `JSON_AGG(columns.*)` or the like to select the entire row for the columns.
- `ANY (ARRAY['r', 't', 'i']` was updated to `IN  ANY ('r', 't', 'i')`

---

EDIT:

In order to bring this into a single column, Let's `COALESCE`, and whenever the new function returns `NULL`, we will insert an array containing the result of the `pg_get_indexdef`, and prefer `ARRAY_AGG` to `JSON_AGG`. All together:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(columns.column_name)
                 FROM information_schema.columns
                WHERE table_schema = 'public'
                  AND table_name   = i.indrelid::regclass::text
                  AND ordinal_position IN (SELECT matches[1]::INTEGER 
                                           FROM regexp_matches(i.indexprs::TEXT,
                                                 'varattno (\d)',
                                                 'g') as matches)), 
                ARRAY[(pg_get_indexdef(att.attrelid, att.attnum, true))]) AS argument_columns
     , i.indrelid::regclass::text AS table
     , c.relname AS index_nameq
     , att.attname as column_names
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute att ON att.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_index     i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid
WHERE  n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
AND    c.relkind IN ('r', 't', 'i');
```

This produces:

| argument_columns | table | index_nameq | column_names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {file_id} | file_lookup_4k | date_index | file_id |
| {file_id} | file_lookup_4k | date2_index | abs |
| {sequence_no} | file_lookup_4k | date3_index | round |
| {sequence_no} | file_lookup_4k | date4_index | round |
| {content} | file_lookup_4k | date5_index | substring |
| {file_id,sequence_no} | file_lookup_4k | date6_index | abs |

Comment: Thanks for the new query. So the column name in showing up in the `argument_columns` array, but if `argument_columns` is null, then it shows up as a string (not array) in the `column_names`?

Comment: Yes - but if you wrap the new array column in `COALESCE` and offered `ARRAY(pg_get_indexdef(att.attrelid, att.attnum, true))` as the second argument to `COALESCE` you would always have an array of one of more strings.

In that case, `JSON_AGG` would have to become `ARRAY_AGG`, or you may have to perform more suitable coersion.... Let me update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `pg_get_indexdef`, like so:

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(att.attrelid, att.attnum, true)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute att ON att.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_index     i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_am        a ON a.oid = c.relam
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (SELECT opc.opcname
                 FROM   unnest(i.indclass::oid[]) WITH ORDINALITY o(oid, ord)
                 JOIN   pg_opclass opc ON opc.oid = o.oid
                 ORDER  BY o.ord)
   ) opc(operator_classes)
WHERE  n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
AND    c.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r', 't', 'i']);
```

| pg_get_indexdef |
| --- |
| "substring"(content, 1, 5) |
| abs(file_id) |
| child_id |
| content_tsv |
| content_tsv |
| content_tsv |
| father_id |
| file_id |
| file_id |
| installed_rank |
| round(sequence_no::double precision) |
| round(sequence_no::double precision) |
| success |

One should recall that an index can refer to multiple columns, and so can a function require multiple columns as arguments.

That said, by retrieving `pg_get_indexdef` and applying a little regexp, we can get our arguments

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(
         regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(pg_get_indexdef(att.attrelid, att.attnum, true), 
                           att.attname, 
                           '', 
                           'g'), 
            '^\w|^,|^\:|"', 
                      '', 
            'g'),
         '\((.+)\)'))[1] AS fn_args
     , pg_get_indexdef(att.attrelid, att.attnum, true) 
     , i.indrelid::regclass::text AS table
     , c.relname AS index_name
     , a.amname AS index_type
     , opc.operator_classes
     , i.indisunique AS is_unique
     , att.attname as column_names
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute att ON att.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_index     i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_am        a ON a.oid = c.relam
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (SELECT opc.opcname
                 FROM   unnest(i.indclass::oid[]) WITH ORDINALITY o(oid, ord)
                 JOIN   pg_opclass opc ON opc.oid = o.oid
                 ORDER  BY o.ord)
   ) opc(operator_classes)
WHERE  n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
AND    c.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r', 't', 'i'])
group by
   i.indrelid, c.relname, a.amname, opc.operator_classes, i.indisunique, att.attrelid, att.attnum
```

Where only indices defined with function calls return rows here:

| fn_args | pg_get_indexdef | table | index_name | index_type | operator_classes | is_unique | column_names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| content, 1, 5 | "substring"(content, 1, 5) | file_lookup_4k | date5_index | btree | {text_ops} | 0 | substring |
| file_id | abs(file_id) | file_lookup_4k | date2_index | btree | {int4_ops} | 0 | abs |
| sequence_no::double precision | round(sequence_no::double precision) | file_lookup_4k | date3_index | btree | {float8_ops} | 0 | round |
| sequence_no::double precision | round(sequence_no::double precision) | file_lookup_4k | date4_index | btree | {float8_ops} | 0 | round |

---

Ultimately, you are getting the function name back because that function call is being used to build the index, and not simply the underlying column.

Look at the `pg_catalog.pg_index.indexprs` column in your query and you will see something like the following, which exposes how the function is indexed:

```
({FUNCEXPR :funcid 1342 :funcresulttype 701 :funcretset false :funcvariadic false :funcformat 0 :funccollid 0 :inputcollid 0 
:args ({FUNCEXPR :funcid 316 :funcresulttype 701 :funcretset false :funcvariadic false :funcformat 2 :funccollid 0 :inputcollid 0 
:args ({VAR :varno 1 :varattno 2 :vartype 23 :vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnosyn 1 :varattnosyn 2 :location 50}) :location -1}) :location 44})
```

Comment: Thanks @jeff-vermeer I was hoping for something simpler. I think what I am going to do is to parse the index definition in Python and extract the information I need without using regex. I try to stay away from Regex unless there is no choice.

Comment: Why use `ANY (ARRAY['r', 't', 'i'])` instead of `IN ('r', 't', 'i')`?

Comment: Why ANY (ARRAY['r', 't', 'i']) instead of IN ('r', 't', 'i') ? Copy Pasta! Good catch